# Google BigQuery app_events_ and app_events_intraday_ stuck with old data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I recently started using BigQuery with Firebase and Google analytics and it was working fine few days ago, but not anymore. As I can see, there are 2 tables:

- **app_events_** that should contains history and
- **app_events_intraday_** that should be current day (realtime)

Today is 13 of July and **app_events_ is "stuck" on 8 of July**:

[image: app_events_]

and the **app_events_intraday_ is "stuck" with data of 9 of July and 10 of July**:

[image]

Is this normal behavior? Has anyone experience with this problem? Is possible that is bug in the platform?

Comment: Is this still happening to you? If that's the case, I'd encourage you to open a private issue in the [Google Cloud issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) with your project number since this problem can not be reproduced and it would be really difficult for anyone in SO community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Firebase changed the way they send data to BigQuery, they used to create a dataset per platform and the tables app_events and app_events_intraday will go in that dataset. Now they send the data in the dataset "analytics_ which contains events and events_intraday tables for all platforms. You may want to check this dataset.